# Create variable that is the previous value of another variable

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am looking to create a variable that is that reflects the previous value of a different variable.

The kicker is that I need to group by two variables as well.  I believe that I should be using `group_by` in dplyr to achieve this. To illustrate the question, consider the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(trial = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
  time = c(180,180,190,190,200, 200),
  node = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
  person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  estimate = seq(1:12))


df = df %>%
  arrange(node, estimate)
df$anticipated = c(NA, 1, 3, NA, 7, 9, NA, 4, 6, NA, 8, 10)

print(df)
   trial time node person estimate anticipated
1      1  180    1      1        1          NA
2      2  190    1      1        3           1
3      3  200    1      1        5           3
4      1  180    1      2        7          NA
5      2  190    1      2        9           7
6      3  200    1      2       11           9
7      1  180    2      1        2          NA
8      2  190    2      1        4           4
9      3  200    2      1        6           6
10     1  180    2      2        8          NA
11     2  190    2      2       10           8
12     3  200    2      2       12          10
```

The task I am trying to achieve is to create the "anticipated" variable, which reflects the previous value of `estimate` for each unique combination of `person` and `node`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work? `df %>% arrange(node, estimate) %>% group_by(node, person) %>% mutate(anticipated = lag(estimate))`

Comment: Wow, yes! Had no oidea about that function.  THanks @ ekoam